Seeking Solutions for Disabling the Guardian Boundary in MR Games on Quest 3
We're currently developing a mixed-reality (MR) game for the Oculus Quest 3, which involves physical movement within a real-world space. To enhance immersion, we utilize the passthrough feature extensively and need to disable the Oculus Guardian boundary system.
Currently, the only way we've found to disable the boundary requires players to activate Developer Mode on their accounts, which isn't ideal for general users. We're looking for alternatives that allow us to disable the Guardian boundary without requiring users to change their account settings.
Additionally, our development process involves recording gameplay, for which the boundary needs to be enabled, but we would like to maintain passthrough vision. Is there a way to enable just the passthrough and disable the boundary for recording purposes?
Has anyone here worked with similar settings or encountered these issues? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!

The Quest Game Optimiser app on itch.io allows you to disable the guardian.
